# Can i use pxssh and pexpect together?

Tags: python, pexpect, pxssh

I'm using a pxssh to make connection to remote server and do a some commands,
after that i need to return a stdout and push it to my html webpage.

This construction is not work because it's give all output (command and output) in string (without any formatting)

```
(pxssh code here)
cmd4 = ls -l /var
s.sendline(cmd4)
s.prompt()
result=s.before
return render_template('results.html', the_results=result)
```

this:

```
(pxssh code here)
cmd4 = ls -l /var
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd4, encoding='utf-8')
return render_template('results.html', the_results=child.read()
```

Not working to because this code performs locally (i don't understand why)